# Multiple openvpn clients/server + hotspot + torrent + pihole

Tags: wireless-networking, openvpn, hotspot, deluge, pihole

I have this setup in my home:

```
Router(internet) <---> (eth0) nanopiK2 (wlan0-hotspot)<---->
                             |
               Ubuntu 18.04 server
                   OpenVPN Server.  PiHole (accessible from openvpn server and internal network).
          Torrent Server (direct connection).
```

Now this is working ok, I can access even from my phone trough openvpn and use pihole from my phone all the time.

Now what I want to acchieve is the next.

```
PiHole (accessible from openvpn server and internal network).
                                           192.168.0.X/24                       192.168.1.X/24
         Router(internet) <---> (eth0) nanopiK2 (wlan0-hotspot)<----> Clients
                               /             |             \
                              /      10.0.0.X/24      \
                             /               |                 \
                            /    OpenVPN Server        \
Torrent Server via one opevpn                       All traffic comming via wlan0 must
client (routing via ports?).                             be routed to use other openvpn
                                                            client different of the one using for torrent.
```

I'm trying several things, but I get the next kind of problems:

1) When I start the hotspot, trough some errors that pihole is using the port for dchp, and I want to keep using that (or is better to use another thing?)

2) When I start any opevpn client is taking over all the connection and I can't connect from local network or from openvpn (all ips are changed).

Any Idea ? It is possible to have working in the same box 1 openvpn server and 2 clients?

Comment: You may want to add more information to the question. An educated guess from using openVPN on other platforms, when openVPN clients connect/disconnect it's changing the **routing** table on the client device. You may need to direct each client device through it's routing table to use the 192.168.0.x for local requests.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking that the setup that I want is kind of really complicated almost impossible. Maybe I will do only one vpn, but somehow that I still can get to the server from internal network. Thanks !